=== Bit is not initialized - reverting to basic git command ===
I am trying to use Bit for the first time. I have followed the documentation and installed it. I have also initialized it by running bit init --default-scope thesis-mf.bit-tutorial. However, if I try to run an of the bit commands. I always get the same error: === Bit is not initialized - reverting to basic git command ===. (Please see the picture). Error message
The initialization created a .bit folder, which contains config.json file. (See picture) Folder created by bit init command
This happens with any bit command (except the bit init). I couldn't find any information regarding this problem, so I was wondering, if someone could help me with this issue. I would be very grateful. Thank you.

The only documentation I can see says "Make sure to create your scope on the Bit platform and use the right org and project name". Did you do that, or are you looking at something else that mentions bit-tutorial?

Sorry, I forgot to mention it in my question. I have created new organization "thesis-mf" and a new scope "bit-tutorial" (scope, not project). So the error might be comming from this fact. The reason I created a scope instead of a project is that I couldn't find anything in regards to "projects" in the bit platform and the only thing I was able to create was either organization or scope. After searching for a bit, I thought that maybe those terms were interchangeble.

how did you install bit on your system? bit doesn't have such warning message at all. can you please run bit --version?

also, bit does not have a .bit/config.json file, which means you many have installed a tool with a similar name, but different functionality.

If you are still running into this issue, please see this https://github.com/teambit/bit/issues/8261 on teambit account.
